# why my loop will not stop even after i enter correct

Tags: java

i had try enter other thing that not related to what i want and it will prompt the else if statement ask me enter again ..but why when i enter the correct thing it still ask me to choose again ??? why ??

here is part of my code  :

```
 public static void choose()
{

    Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
    String shape = "";


    do{

    System.out.println("which shape you would like to choose");
    shape=read.nextLine();     
    if(shape.equals("rectangle"))
    {
        System.out.println("enter width");
         width=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter length");
        length=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter color");
       String color = read.nextLine();


    }
    else if (shape.equals("box"))
    {
        System.out.println("enter width");
         width=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter length");
        length=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter height");
        height=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter color");
        String color = read.nextLine();


    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("please enter only rectangle and box");

    }

    }while((shape !="rectangle" && shape !="box"));
```

here my run  :

```
which shape you would like to choose
abc
please enter only rectangle and box
which shape you would like to choose
box
enter width
9
enter length
8
enter height
8
 enter color
  blue
 which shape you would like to choose
```

Comment: ***shape !="rectangle"*** never ever in java with strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `equals` method in your loop condition not the operator `!=`. So the correct version is:

```
} while(!"rectangle".equals(shape) && !"box".equals(shape));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
shape !="rectangle" && shape !="box"
```

to

```
!shape.equals("rectangle") && !shape.equals("box")
```

for the same reason for which you are using it inside your `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your test in the `while` statement is not correct as said by others.

But you can remove it by adding `break;` at the end of each blocks (except the one that ask to input again) :

```
do{

System.out.println("which shape you would like to choose");
shape=read.nextLine();     
if(shape.equals("rectangle"))
{
    System.out.println("enter width");
     width=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
    System.out.println("enter length");
    length=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
    System.out.println("enter color");
   String color = read.nextLine();

    break; // Exit loop here
}
else if (shape.equals("box"))
{
    System.out.println("enter width");
    width=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
    System.out.println("enter length");
    length=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
    System.out.println("enter height");
    height=Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
    System.out.println("enter color");
    String color = read.nextLine();

    break; // Exit loop here
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("please enter only rectangle and box");

}

}while(true);
```

If you have few cases and/or the test is time consuming, this is a viable alternative since you are testing each value only once.